# no random initialization in opencv kmeans when using boost::threadGroup

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means, boost-thread

I keep on getting the same results when using opencv kmeans inside a boost::threadGroup (for multi-threading) although I'm using the `KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS` flag (randomness is working when not using boost::thread group).

This is how I call my kmeans in a boost::threadGroup:

```
boost::thread_group threadGroup
for(int i=0; i < numDescs; i++)
{
    threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind( &applyKmeansRand, matDescs[i], matCenters[i], numClusters));
}
threadGroup.join_all();
```

This is the function I'm calling:

```
void applyKmeansRand(Mat& matDesc,Mat& matCenters,int numClusters)
{
    Mat bestlabels;

    TermCriteria criteria;
    kmeans(matDesc, numClusters, bestlabels, criteria, 1, KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS, matCenters );
}
```

Is there a possibility that the random number generator inside the kmeans function is not working properly?

Comment: Does it generate the same numbers after each run or after each compilation? The former is a seeding issue, the latter is a... bigger problem.

Comment: Even after recompilation... I even set the number of max iterations to 1, still I keep on getting the same output after every run and compilation. I'm running kmeans inside a `threadGroup.create_thread` block for parrallelisation, maybe that is somehow killing the random initilisation?
Maybe some explicit random seeding could help also...

Comment: Seems indeed to be a problem with boost::threadGroup I will adapt my question and look further for an answer. In the worst case I'll have to parrallelize my code differently then with using boost::threadGroup

Answer (score 0):

Though I could not resolve the problem using `boost::threadGroup` which mysteriously seems to use always the same seeding for random number generator integrated in `cv::kmeans`. I ended up doing the parallel processing of kmeans using `openmp`:

```
// Include openmp header
#include <omp.h>
[...]

// Some kmeans options / variables
int numIter = 100;
int numRepetitions= 10;   
Mat bestlabels;
[...]

// Execute kmeans in parallel
#pragma omp parallel for   
for(int i=0; i < numDescs; i++)
{
        TermCriteria criteria = TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, numIter, FLT_EPSILON);
        kmeans(matDescs[i], numClusters, bestlabels, criteria, numRepetitions, KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS, matCenters[i] );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You say you're calling `applyKmeansRand`, but your code says you call `applyKmeansNTrajpRand`; any chance that's the problem?

Probably not, but if the NTrajp version has the same signature as one shown, then the problem may be the way you bind it. By default, `bind` captures arguments *by value*, so the `Mat` objects your function receives are references to *copies* of the ones you give to `bind`. Thus, you store the results of your calculations into what are essentially temporary objects rather than into the objects already in your arrays.

Use `boost::ref` to bind to references instead of copies:

```
boost::bind(&applyKmeansNTrajpRand, boost::ref(matDescs[i]), boost::ref(matCenters[i]), numClusters)
```

Comment: Yes the different names were a typo. I fixed that in my question. Thanks for pointing out.
Concerning the passing by a  boost reference wrapper. That version does not compile for me, giving an error: `error: in passing argument 1 of ‘const boost::reference_wrapper<T> boost::ref(T&) [with T = cv::Mat]’
 template<class T> inline reference_wrapper<T> BOOST_REF_CONST ref(T & t)`
Maybe that's because boost::ref cannot handle cv::Mat objects? Do I need to modify the function `applyKmeansRand` as well?

Comment: "so the Mat objects your function receives are references to copies"  -- cv::Mat is essentially a smart pointer

Comment: Hmm ok, so how would I use `boost::ref()` given that cv::Mat is a smart pointer?

Comment: If it's really a smart pointer, then it shouldn't need to be passed by reference at all — no `boost::ref`, and no `&`, either.

Comment: Ok. So then I compile everything as before. Actually the problem is not that the result / output of kmeans looks bad, it's just that the seeding of random numbers used for the initialisation of `kmeans` is ALWAYS the same, both after recompiling and rerunning the program. It seems that boost::threadGroup is running in a thread where opencv::kmeans always gets the same seeding for its random number generator.
Did anybody ever parralelize his `cv::kmeans` in `c++`?